# How to search for high coverage SRA entries

Tags: ngs, database, public-databases, phylogenetics

#### The Question

I want to find high coverage SRA entries, e.g., above 100x.

I guess the best way is to use https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sra with an appropriate search term. I don't mind if the search results contain some "false-positives". (I.e., if some of the found entries have coverage above 80x, while I aimed for 100x, that's fine.)
I want to avoid using Entrez.esummary on a very large number of SRA entries (e.g., through Biopython), as it would be significantly slower (if I understand correctly).

How can I do that?

---

#### My Attempt

I tried using the `Mbases` field.
Assuming the reference genome is at most 100kbp (e.g., in case I am interested in viruses), I thought a good approximation would be to search for SRA entries with more than 100*100k bases, i.e., at least 10M bases.
According to https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK3837/, I thought I could use the search term `10:9999999[Mbases]`, but disappointingly, this didn't work. Just to make sure my syntax is right, I verified that `100:101[ReadLength]` works. So it seems that `Mbases` doesn't support the range syntax.

Answer (score 1):

If processing a huge table with lots of "false positives" is OK, then you could enter your search term, from top right choose "Send to" > "File" Format: "RunInfo".